# preg match all chars and whitespaces included

Tags: php, regex

I want to match everything starting from the line `/Subtype /Widget` until the line `<<`

With this code nothing is matched

```
preg_match('#/Subtype /Widget([.\s]*)<<#', $pdf, $matches);
```

subject

```
522 0 obj 
<<
/Subtype /Widget
/V (some text)
/T (Kreditor)
/Rect [54.6 359.16 296.4 531.84]
/P 414 0 R
/DA (/Helv 8 Tf 0 g)
/Ff 8392704
/Type /Annot
/F 4
/TU (Kreditor:)
/AP 
<<
/N 534 0 R
```

Comment: `.` matches across lines when you add `s` modifier. `'#/Subtype /Widget(.*?)<<#s'`. Note you might also need a lazy quantifier, `*?`, rather than `*` greedy one, if you have multiple occurrences in the string.

Comment: great answer.. I already tried with `/s` but `*?` did it :) thanks